# How can I add some Enum values to a combobox

Tags: c#, enums

In the following example I would like to add flavours that start with "APPLE" to a ComboBox on a form.  When the enums have unique values it works fine; however, in my example two enums PINEAPPLE_PEACH and APPLE_ORANGE both have a value of 1 and this messes up the results.

Is it erroneous to have two enums with the same value and, if so, how can I change my code to get consistent results?

```
    public enum Flavour
    {
        APPLE_PEACH = 0,
        PINEAPPLE_PEACH = 1,
        APPLE_ORANGE = 1,
        APPLE_BANANA = 3,
        PINEAPPLE_GRAPE = 4
    }

    private void AddFlavours()
    {
        foreach (Flavour flavour in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Flavour)))
        {
            string flavourName = Enum.GetName(typeof(Flavour), flavour);
            if (flavourName.StartsWith("APPLE"))
            {
                myComboBox.Items.Add(flavour);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use iteration described by Konamiman. But anyway, why do you ever need duplicates in enum values?

Comment: it's actually an enum from a third-party library so I have no choice :).  Above code is for illustration purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enum to comboBox except some of enum elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047167/enum-to-combobox-except-some-of-enum-elements)

Answer (score 1):

With Linq, you may use this:

```
foreach (string flavourName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Flavour)).Where(s => s.StartsWith("APPLE")))     
{
    myComboBox.Items.Add(flavourName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) instead of GetValues. It would be something like this (not tested):

```
 foreach (string flavourName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Flavour)))
 {
     if (flavourName.StartsWith("APPLE"))
     {
         myComboBox.Items.Add(Enum.Parse(typeof(flavour), flavourName));
     }
 }
```

Comment: You need to change Flavour to string.