# enum to comboBox except some of enum elements

Tags: c#

For example I have enum:

```
private enum Categories
{
foo,
fooBar,
Bar
}
```

At this way i fill comboBox by elements of enum:

```
myComboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categories)).Cast<Categories>();
```

But how bind to enum all elements except `Categories.fooBar` for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `Where`:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categories))
      .Cast<Categories>()
      .Where(x => x != Categories.fooBar).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **Except**(): If you need to add exceptions, you only need to add these items to the list exceptValues or in the inline declaration.

```
var exceptValues = new[] {Categories.fooBar};
var source = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categories)).Cast<Categories>().Except(exceptValues);
```

Or

```
var source = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categories)).Cast<Categories>().Except( new[] {Categories.fooBar})
```

Cheers.

Comment: Im with you @ Giora Guttsait, a WHERE do not suit very well in this case.